# How to COUNT distinct multiple columns

Tags: informix

Would anyone know how to count the number of records using distinct but with multiple columns?

An example of what I want would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a, b, c, d)
FROM temp
```

I am using Informix.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the job (assuming a sufficiently recent version of Informix):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d FROM temp);
```

The inner SELECT generates the list of distinct combinations of the columns `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`; the outer SELECT counts the number of rows generated by the inner SELECT.

It's unlikely that you don't have a sufficiently recent version of Informix.

> Unfortunately I have version 9 of Informix and that doesn't work for me.

I wish I wasn't as prescient — you don't have a sufficiently recent version of Informix.  If you're using an obsolete version of Informix, it is important to say which version when you ask the question.  Assuming you're using 9.40 (the latest version in the 9.x family, first released in 2003) and not some even more antique version such as 9.00 (from 1996), then there are versions 10.00, 11.10, 11.50 and 11.70 that have all been released since your version, and these versions have also all been removed from support.  The currently supported versions are 12.10 and 14.10.  You *should* upgrade to 14.10.  *(If you ask more questions about Informix, please include your version number in the question.  You'll get a better answer in the first pass.)*

Your simplest alternative is to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d FROM temp INTO TEMP distinct_a_b_c_d;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM distinct_a_b_c_d;
DROP TABLE distinct_a_b_c_d;
```

Given that you're using version 9.x, you can't even use the protective `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS distinct_a_b_c_d;` before the sequence to remove a pre-existing table.

I'm not sure whether there are any feasible alternatives to creating the intermediate result table (which could be a permanent table, at a pinch, but that's problematic for a variety of reasons).

Comment: Unfortunately I have version 9 of informix and that doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I've suggested alternative SQL syntax that will work in version 9.40 or earlier.  Please include your version number in the question when it is as out of date as that — you'll get better answers.  You should upgrade to 14.10.  I know that is out of your control, but you are using software first released in 2003.  It went to EOS (end of service — out of support) on [2009-04-30](https://www.cursor-distribution.de/en/ibm-software/support-informix/informix-lifecycle-tab-en).

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) 
from table (
    multiset(select distinct a, b, c, d from temp)
) a;
```